# RSpec-rails | Description of Finding an Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

How can I describe of finding an associated model in the RSpec-rails controller examples?

I try the following:

**Article**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**CommentsControllerSpec**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article) { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment) { stub_model Comment }

    before { Article.stub(:find) { article } }
    before { article.stub(:comments) { [comment] } }

    it 'finds a comment' do
      article.comments.should_receive(:find) { comment }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**CommentsController**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    Article.find.comments.find
  end
end
```

But unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tackled the problem by myself.

Here's the approximate list of actions to describe of finding an associated model in the Rails' controllers.

**1.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
  end
end
```

**2.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    it 'finds an article' # <=
  end
end
```

**3.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find) # <=
      put :update                   # <=
    end
  end
end
```

**4.**

```
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"update"}
```

**5.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article) { stub_model Article } # <=

    it 'finds a article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id # <=
    end
  end
end
```

**6.**

```
No route matches \
  {:article_id=>"1025", :controller=>"comments", :action=>"update"}
```

**7.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article) { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment) { stub_model Comment } # <=

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id # <=
    end
  end
end
```

**8.**

```
(<Article (class)>).find(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

**9.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    Article.find
  end
end
```

**10.**

```
Success!
```

**11.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article) { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment) { stub_model Comment }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**12.**

```
<Article (class)> received :find with unexpected arguments
  expected: ("1025")
       got: (no args)
```

**13.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    Article.find(params[:article_id]) # <=
  end
end
```

**14.**

```
Success!
```

**15.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {                                    # <=
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation) # <=
    }                                                      # <=

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do                               # <=
      article.stub(:comments) { association }             # <=
      association.should_receive(:find)                   # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id # <=
    end                                                   # <=
  end
end
```

**16.**

```
Couldn't find Article with id=1027
```

**17.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation)
    }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article } # <=
      article.stub(:comments) { association }
      association.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**18.**

```
(Mock ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation).find(any args)
    expected: 1 time
    received: 0 times
```

**19.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    Article.find(params[:article_id]).comments.find # <=
  end
end
```

**20.**

```
update
  finds an article (fail!)
  finds a comment  (success!)

undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

**21.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation)
    }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article } # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      article.stub(:comments) { association }
      association.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**22.**

```
update
  finds an article (fail!)
  finds a comment  (success!)

Couldn't find Comment without an ID
```

**23.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation)
    }

    before { article.stub(:comments) { association } } # <=

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      # -> article.stub(:comments) { association } <-
      association.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**24.**

```
update
  finds an article (fail!)
  finds a comment  (success!)

Mock ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation \
  received unexpected message :find with (no args)
```

**25.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation).as_null_object # <=
    }

    before { article.stub(:comments) { association } }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      association.should_receive(:find)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**26.**

```
Success!
```

**27.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      mock(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation).as_null_object
    }

    before { article.stub(:comments) { association } }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      association.should_receive(:find).with(comment.id.to_s) # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end
  end
end
```

**28.**

```
Mock ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation \
  received :find with unexpected arguments
  expected: ("1028")
       got: (no args)
```

**29.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    Article.find(params[:article_id]).comments.find(params[:id]) # <=
  end
end
```

**30.**

```
Success!
```

**31.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      double(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation).as_null_object # <=
    }

    before { article.stub(:comments) { association } }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      association.should_receive(:find).with(comment.id.to_s)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'assigns @comment' do                              # <=
      Article.stub(:find) { article }                     # <=
      association.stub(:find) { comment }                 # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id # <=
      assigns[:comment].should eq comment                 # <=
    end                                                   # <=
  end
end
```

**32.**

```
expected: #<Comment >
     got: nil
```

**33.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @comment = Article.find(params[:article_id]).comments.find(params[:id]) # <=
  end
end
```

**34.**

```
Success!
```

**35.**

```
describe CommentsController do
  describe 'update' do
    let(:article)     { stub_model Article }
    let(:comment)     { stub_model Comment }
    let(:association) {
      double(ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation).as_null_object
    }

    before { article.stub(:comments) { association } }

    it 'finds an article' do
      Article.should_receive(:find).with(article.id.to_s) { article }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'finds a comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      association.should_receive(:find).with(comment.id.to_s)
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
    end

    it 'assigns @article' do                              # <=
      Article.stub(:find) { article }                     # <=
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id # <=
      assigns[:article].should eq article                 # <=
    end                                                   # <=

    it 'assigns @comment' do
      Article.stub(:find) { article }
      association.stub(:find) { comment }
      put :update, article_id: article.id, id: comment.id
      assigns[:comment].should eq comment
    end
  end
end
```

**36.**

```
expected: #<Article >
     got: nil
```

**37.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])   # <=
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id]) # <=
  end
end
```

**38.**

```
Success!
```

**39.**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_article, only: :update # <=
  before_filter :find_comment, only: :update # <=

  def update
    # -> @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])   <-
    # -> @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id]) <-
  end

  private                                          # <=
    def find_article                               # <=
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id]) # <=
    end                                            # <=

    def find_comment                                 # <=
      @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id]) # <=
    end                                              # <=
end
```

**40.**

```
Success!
```

Comment: I'm a Rails fan, but this is why people hate Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, replace:

```
before { article.stub(:comments) { [comment] } }
```

With:

```
before { article.stub_chain(:comments, :find) { [comment] } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, **apneadiving**.

As far as a understand `obj.stub` and `obj.should_receive` behaves the similar way — they create a method for a double. So, why should I specify the `find` method twice: in the before block `article.stub_chain(:comments, :find)` and in the example `article.comments.should_receive(:find)`?

Comment: @Shamaoke: You use `stub` to set a return value of a method call. You use `should_receive` to set up an expectation.